Help with Analytic Function Zero in Annulus
I'm working on a problem involving an analytic function in an annulus, and I need some help with the second part of the question. Here is the problem statement:
Suppose that $ f(z) $ is analytic in the annulus $ D(0; 1, 2) = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid 1 < |z| < 2 \} $ and is continuous in $ \overline {D(0; 1, 2)} $ with
$
\max_{|z|=1} |f(z)| \leq 1 \quad \text{and} \quad \max_{|z|=2} |f(z)| \leq 2.
$
Prove:

$ |f(z)| \leq |z| $ for all $ z \in D(0; 1, 2) $.

If $ f(z) $ is not of the form $ e^{i\theta} z $, $ |f(z)| \equiv 1 $ for $ |z| = 1 $, and $ |f(z)| \equiv 2 $ for $ |z| = 2 $, then $ f(z) $ has a zero in $ D(0; 1, 2) $, i.e., there exists $ z_0 \in D(0; 1, 2) $  such that $ f(z_0) = 0 $


I have successfully shown the first part, but I am having trouble with the second part. Here is what I have tried so far:
I attempted a proof by contradiction. Suppose () has no zeros in the annulus
(0;1,2)
. Then  $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is analytic in (0;1,2). By the maximum modulus principle, the maximum and minimum modulus of $f(z)$ are both attained on the boundary.
At this point, I am unsure how to proceed. I would appreciate any hints or detailed explanations on how to tackle this problem.

presumably close to what you did in part 1 [showing your work here is relevant] is to consider $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z}$ and observe it sends the boundary to 1 so apply https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744904/non-constant-holomorphic-function-on-an-annulus-with-constant-modulus-on-boundar/ ... the fact that if $g$ is non-constant it must have at least two zeros is a bit more than what your problem is asking

Instead of going for a contradiction, you could go for a proof by contrapositive. That is, if $|f(z)| \equiv 1$ on $\{|z| = 1\}$ and $|f(z)| \equiv 2$ on $\{|z| = 2\}$, and if $f$ does not vanish on $D(0; 1, 2)$, then it must be of the form $f(z) = e^{i\theta}z$ for some $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. To show this requires only a small adjustment to your initial try.
Let $g : D(0; 1, 2) \to \mathbb{C}$ be the holomorphic function defined by $g(z) = f(z)/z$, which is also continuous on $\overline{D(0; 1, 2)}$. Then $|g(z)| \equiv 1$ on both $\{|z| = 1\}$ and $\{|z| = 2\}$, and so the maximum modulus principle implies that $|g(z)| \leq 1$ for all $z \in \overline{D(0; 1, 2)}$. Now, because $f$ has no zeros in $\overline{D(0; 1, 2)}$ by assumption, the function $1/g(z) = z/f(z)$ is also holomorphic on $D(0; 1, 2)$ and is continuous on $\overline{D(0; 1, 2)}$. So the maximum modulus principle applies again to give $1/|g(z)| \leq 1$ for all $z \in \overline{D(0; 1, 2)}$. This implies that $|g(z)| \equiv 1$ on $\overline{D(0; 1, 2)}$, or in other words, that $g$ is a constant with value $e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus, $f(z) = e^{i\theta} z$, as was to be shown.
